# Django modify templates of pip-installed app

Tags: python, django, notifications, django-templates, django-notification

I'm wondering what the proper way to override templates for an app installed via pip. My example pertains to the [django-notifications](https://github.com/brantyoung/django-notifications) app. The structure is as follows:

```
notifications
|---- __init__.py
|---- templates
      |---- notifications
            |---- list.html
            |---- notice.html
```

I have duplicated this structure in my app and modified the .html files accordingly. However now I am faced with the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name notify` which occurs when in a view from another app (profile) where I call `from notifications import notify`.

Without overriding the templates I get no errors. What am I missing? Is there something additional I need to add to the settings.py?

(I have followed the README.md Installation Instructions in the package exactly and have it working properly without overriding templates)

#### Trackback

```
File "/projectpath/project/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
  url(r'^profile/', include('profile.urls')),

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 26, in include
  urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
  __import__(name)

File "/projectpath/profile/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
  from profile import views

File "/projectpath/profile/views.py", line 17, in <module>
    from notifications import notify

ImportError: cannot import name notify
```

#### View

```
from notifications import notify

def edit(request):
  ...
  notify.send(request.user, recipient=request.user, verb='you reached level 10')
```

#### Settings

```
# Project directory root assuming: yunite.settings.base
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)

#ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)


# Directory to find templates
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child("templates"),
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'notifications',
)
```

Comment: did you resolve this? I too am stuck at this. And the annoying part is that I've written a custom app with the name `notifications`. Now, I come to think about it, it seems that there is something in the app name itself.

Comment: Strangely enough, after restructuring the app with other name than `notifications` worked just fine. That's weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding a template in Django is simple. In your main application directory, there must be a templates directory (create if not already). Then create a new directory inside the template directory, which is named (notifications) in your case. Then copy the template files here (`list.html` and `notice.html`) in your case.

When done, you have overridden the app templates with your own templates. Feel free to edit them.

Comment: well yes it is supposed to be easy and that's what I have done first, but there is something unknown going on here that's making it much more difficult

Comment: Honestly, I don't see it as an issue with templates from your traceback. Would you mind sharing the settings file and the apps code where you are using the notifications app?

Comment: posted. not sure if you want to see anything else in settings

Comment: Okay, here is a simple way to debug this. First do a `pip freeze` to see if you have actually installed the app in the project's virtualenv. Next, open `python manage.py shell` and try importing notify. Also, if you are not using ipython already, do that. It is really helpful in debugging with autocomplete.

Comment: `pip freeze` shows: `django-notifications-hq==0.6.0`. `python manage.py shell shows`: `ImportError: cannot import name notify`. no help unfortunately

Comment: Would this have anything to do with the app using `include(notifications.urls)` instead of `include('notifications.urls')`?

Comment: Nope, this is fine. This shows you are not able to import notify. That's precisely the issue.

Comment: Nope the url path is right. It shouldn't be in quotes. I installed the app and tried importing notify. It was successful. For sure, it is an issue with your import.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51151/discussion-between-vinit-and-matt-stokes)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking: did you add "notifications" to the INSTALLED_APPS? This sounds like the overridden template just makes the import error visible.

Comment: yepp it has already been added. There is no import error and everything works fine if I do not override the template

Comment: The importing isn't done in the templates. You can examine the traceback to see how the offending code is called. I'm quite sure that the templates just make a problem visible that arises elsewhere.

Comment: I have included a trackback

Comment: There is no hint to the templates in the traceback. When you know why views.py cannot import from notifications, you'll have the solution. Another random idea: is there any folder named "notifications" that is considered a module by views.py?

Comment: I do have an __init__.py file in the notifications directory. Without this it runs perfect but does not override the template